# shared preference array data save in emtpty array in android

Tags: android, arrays, json, sharedpreferences

I am new with android. I'm working Json with shared preferences. From the json I am getting the data and save into the shared preferences and it's working fine.  I want to assign the shared preference array data to string in SharedPreferences.

This is the code:

```
      private ArrayList<String>urls2 = new ArrayList<>();
         private ArrayList<String>urls1 = new ArrayList<>();

        this is the json parse 
          if (errorCode == 0) {
                        email = p.getString("email");
                        firstName = p.getString("firstName");
                        lastName = p.getString("lastName");
                        phone = p.getString("phone");
                        status = p.getString("status");
                        updatedDate = p.getString("updatedDate");
                        serverURL = p.getString("url");
                        urls1.add(p.getString("url"));

        //                    urls1.append(",");
                        Log.d("URL", "" + urls1);
                        urls2.add(p.getString("staffId"))                   urls2.append(",");
                        Log.d("STAFFID", "" + urls2);

        }
SharedPreferences:

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("LOGINACTIVITY", 0).edit();


                            for(int i=0;i<urls2.size();i++) {
                                editor.putString("staffId1" + i, urls2.get(i));
                                Log.d("staffId1",urls2.get(i).toString());
                            }

                            for(int i=0;i<urls1.size();i++) {
                                editor.putString("serverURL" + i, urls1.get(i));
                                Log.d("SavedURl",urls1.get(i).toString());



                       }

 in next view controller i want assing the shared preference array data string 

         like ex : firsturl = arrayshared[0]

                  secondurl = arrayshared[1]

            this is next view controller 

             ArrayList<String> staffdata = new ArrayList<String>();

                    int listsize = mPrefsManager.getInt("staffId1", 0);

                    Log.d("firstcall of<<<<<<<",""+listsize);

                     for(int i=0; i<=listsize; i++) {

                        if(listsize == 0)
                        {

                        Hear : first shared preference array first element data 

                            like ex : firsturl = arrayshared[0]

                            Log.d("firstcall of<<<<<<<",""+listsize);
                            firsturl = .get(i).toString() 

                        }
                         else
                        {

                       like : secondurl = arrayshared[1]
                        ===> hear  second url data 
                            Log.d("second irst<<<",""+listsize);
                        }
```

how to get the data from the shared preference array to string

Comment: you forgot to add `editor.commit();` without commit it will not save any data

Comment: i did that but my issue is sharedpreference array data to string

Comment: "pls help me" you need to be older than 13 to participate on this site. If you are, act like it

Answer (score 0):

the right way to use Shared Preferences (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#ReadSharedPreference) is:

1. to Write to Shared Preferences:

`SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("Your Key name", yourString);
editor.commit();`

2. to Read from Shared Preferences:

`SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String defaultValue = "default String";
String mString = sharedPref.getString("Your Key name", defaultValue);`

So:

step 1: we have stored the value of `yourString` inside the preferece that has the key call `"Your Key name"`;

step 2: we have read the preference and store his value inside the `mString` variable.

So you can easily use a loop to store the strings inside your arraylist (every elements of your list have to have a different key) and use another loop to read the preference and add every preference into another list.

For a better use don't forget to store the lenght of the ArrayList inside the preferences.

For example, to write an arrayList of String into SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("lengtArrayList", lengtOfTheArrayList);
for (int i = 0; i < lengtOfTheArrayList; i++) {
    editor.putString("Your Key name" + i, yourArrayList.get(i));
}
editor.commit();
```

To read and store inside another Arraylist:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int size = sharedPref.getInt("lengtArrayList", 0);
String defaultValue = "default String";
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    String mString = sharedPref.getString("Your Key name" + i, defaultValue);
    mArrayList.add(mString);
};
```

I hope that it can help you:D

Good luck!!

For example try this snippet of code into a new project and see the logcat:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList1.add("ciao");
    arrayList1.add("come");
    arrayList1.add("stai");

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("lengtArrayList", arrayList1.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList1.size(); i++) {
        editor.putString("p" + i, arrayList1.get(i));
    }
    editor.commit();

    ArrayList<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    int size = sharedPref.getInt("lengtArrayList", 0);
    String defaultValue = "default String";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        String mString = sharedPref.getString("p" + i, defaultValue);
        Log.v("Preference = ", mString);
        arrayList2.add(mString);
        Log.v("Array = ", arrayList2.get(i));
    };
}
```

}

Comment: int size = mPrefsManager.getInt("staffId1", 0);
        String defaultValue = "default String";
        for (int i = 0; i <=size; i++) {
//            String mString = mPrefsManager.getString("s",i,"defatu");
            String mString = mPrefsManager.getString("staffId1" + i, defaultValue);

            Data.add(mString);

            Log.d("data addes hea of<<<<<", "" + Data);
      } if i can try am getting the null values

Comment: String mString = mPrefsManager.getString("staffId1" + i, defaultValue); i want get the staffid on there

Comment: Using my method you create x preferences. Every preference have the key = "Your Key name" + i.

Comment: Using my method you create x preferences. Every preference have the key = "Your Key name" + i. The first preference have the value of the lenght of the array, so I called this preference "lengtArrayList". So, before you have to get the value of the preference that contains the lenght of the array, then you have to create a loop using this value and then get the string inside every preference -> String mString =  sharedPref.getString("Your Key name" + i, defaultValue); Then add this value into the list -> Data.add(mString)

Comment: You have to be sure that the values of -> int size = mPrefsManager.getInt("staffId1", 0); is the lenght of your arrayList

Comment: Or, better, create another preference that have the key name "lengtArrayList" that contains the size of the array. Later ->  int size = mPrefsManager.getInt("lengtArrayList", 0);